Is there any way to properly display negative time spans in excel?
Is there any way to make Excel show a negative time span? If I subtract two time values (say, when subtracting the actual amount of time spent on something from the amount of time planned for it) and the result is negative, Excel just fills the result cell with hashes to notify me that the result cannot be displayed as a time value. Even OpenOffice.org Calc and Google Spreadsheets can display negative time values.
Is there a way to work around that issue by using conditional formatting? I really don't want to create some workaround by calculating the hours and minutes myself or anything like that.

The most common reason for displaying hashes instead of a date-time (or any other value) is that the column is too narrow. Have you tried dragging the result column wider? Note that this applies to LibreOffice Calc, as well.

This is an exact duplicate of Is there any way to properly display negative time spans in Excel?.

Downvotes are for bad questions, not duplicates. Let's not downvote questions if they're well written, and edit them if they're badly formatted.

Navigate to:

Preferences
Formulars and Lists
Calculation

Check the checkbox: Use 1904 date system.
Excel will now display negative times (times starting with -).

If you are using Office on Windows, locate to: File > Options > Advanced, under "When calculating this workbook", tick the box of "Use 1904 date system".
